# Add innerhtml to top links

Tags: php, html, magento, innerhtml, magento-1.7

I am trying to add a small innerhtml function to the top links of Magento. Instead of the default text links, I have hidden the texts ('My account', 'My wishlist', 'My cart', 'login/register') and given them images.

See the image below.

[image: innerhtml-on-toplink-hover]

What I'm trying to do is, that when you hover over one of the top links buttons, you get the appropriate label/name of that top link somewhere in a div next to the buttons. So if you hover over the 'My cart' link/button, you get to see the text 'My cart' in that corresponding div.

The technical issue is *not* the innerhtml part, because I know how innerhtml works. My question is: **Where and how do I implement the pieces of innerhtml code so that it works correctly for all the 4 toplinks?**

(Basically, it doesn't really matter that these text links are made into image links, but this is so you won't ask yourself "why would he want to do that?".)

---

What I've tried is to add the parts to

*mystore\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\template\links.phtml*

or (never both)

*mystore\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\template\linksblock.phtml*.
I used the following code pieces:

`<script type="text/javascript">
        function changeDescription(content) {
            document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = content;
        }
    </script>`

`<a href="#" onmouseover="changeDescription('<?php echo $this->getTitle() ?>')">
    <!-- I also tried getLabel() instead of getTitle() -->`

`<div id="description">
      lorem ipsum
    </div>`

And tried put in different places in those files (separately), but wherever I place the code, it messes up the `<ul>` list and its list items.

---

p.s. these 'buttons' are f*ugly, I know. It's just temporarily ;)

---

**Edit:**

My best try (amongst other different things I), probably, was to put it in links.phtml like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function changeDescription(content) { document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = content; } </script>
<div id="description"> lorem ipsum </div>
<?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
<?php if(count($_links)>0): ?>
<ul class="links"<?php if($this->getName()): ?> id="<?php echo $this->getName() ?>"<?php endif;?>>
    <?php foreach($_links as $_link): ?>
    <a href="#" title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getLabel()); ?>" onmouseover="changeDescription(this.title)">
        <?php if ($_link instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract):?>
            <?php echo $_link->toHtml() ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <li<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()||$_link->getIsLast()): ?> class="<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if($_link->getIsLast()): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_link->getLiParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getBeforeText() ?><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_link->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $_link->getAParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a><?php echo $_link->getAfterText() ?></li>
       <?php endif;?>
       </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but to no avail. Whatever I do, it messes up the structure of the contents of the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
<a href="#"
    title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getTitle()); ?>"
    onmouseover="changeDescription(this.title)">
...</a>
```

Note that you've got a mismatch between `content` and `inhoud` in your changeDescsription function.

Comment: Oh yeah, 'inhoud' is Dutch for 'content', I forgot to change that here but there's no mismatch in the code I actually used ;) I'll edit the question

Comment: Still no luck so far, I just can't figure out where to put the pieces of code. See the update in my question.